# Get entity field annotations from hibernate interceptor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to do some additional business logic for specified filed (with a custom annotation) after hibernate load this entity. So, I created a hibernate interceptor like this. But what confused me is that I can't get the annotation information. The encryptAnnotation is always null in the following codes.

```
public class HibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    public boolean onLoad(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
            Type type = types[i];
            if (type instanceof StringType) {
                StringType stringType = (StringType) types[i];
                Encrypt encryptAnnotation = stringType.getJavaTypeDescriptor().getJavaTypeClass().getAnnotation(Encrypt.class);
                if (encryptAnnotation != null) {
                    //todo: decrypt field
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the Entity and annotation definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class Trade implements Serializable {
    @Encrypt
    private String shiptoAddr;
}
```

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Encrypt {
}
```

Comment: Of course you cannot as you aren't doing anything with the `Entity`. You are checking the class of the type descriptor which will never have that annotation. You must check the fields of your entity for the annotation.

Comment: You are correct. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to obtain the annotation from the mapping information and basically in the end you are trying to find the annotation on the `String` class, that is obviously not going to work.

Instead you need to detected all fields on the passed in `entity` object and check if the annotation is present on a field.